# reactjs navbar design proglem(using bootstrap css internally)

Tags: css, reactjs, navbar

I have a problem with the navigation bar,

I have a navigation bar for my project. As you can see my code below if I use the link and get it from an external source it is working well. But there is a problem for me when the net is a bit slow I can see the navigation's loading on my screen. it is a very small duration but it disturbs me very much. So I decided to use CSS source from my project folder but could not do that. I tried many code samples but could not do it correctly. If somebody helps me, I will appreciate it. Thanks.
I am also still trying to solve it but I wanted to get some help.

```
function MyNavBar(params) {
  //console.log(params["conpanyID"]);
  return (
    <div>
      <head>
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        />
      </head>
```

1-When I use link/external source
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO5qB.png
2-When I use CSS file from my project folder.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqHqo.png

Answer (score 0):

you might have linked your stylesheet inside the body instead of the header section , because of which your page will load first, then your CSS

here is an example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>file</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/s.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="css/si.ico">
</head>
```

Comment: No i used it in the header section. But you gave a idea and when i was trying it, i found the solution. When i use local css file there was an error in css file so the app gave me error, now i added it and removed the which the css file was looking for a font file in the same server. So it worked now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: And now my code like below. I removed the header section. I do not see the loading navigation now.

import Style from "./css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/js/src/collapse.js";

function MyNavBar(params) {
  //console.log(params["conpanyID"]);
  return (
    <div>
      <nav class="navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">

Comment: It is interesting that. When i write my problem to here i can solve it easily. But when i struggle on my self it takes more and more times. It is really good. Thanks to stackoverflow. makes me solve my problems faster.